# ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE error

Tags: javascript, angular, mongodb

I'm having issues getting data from an API while learning Angular 2. This is the error I'm getting

> url.js:106 throw new errors.TypeError('ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE', 'url', 'string', url);
>   TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "url" argument must be of type string. Received type undefined at Url.parse (url.js:106:11)

This is the code I'm working with

index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

require('dotenv').config();

let database;

MongoClient.connect(process.env.DB_CONN, (err, db) => {

console.log('connected to mongodb...');

app.listen(3000, () => {
    database = db;
    console.log('listening on port 3000...')
});
});

app.get('/contacts', (req, res) => {
const contactsCollection = database.collection('contacts');

contactsCollection.find({}).toArray((err, docs) => {
    if(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    return res.json(docs);
});
});
```

.env

```
DB_CONN=mongodb://admin:password@ds117931.mlab.com:17931/dem-contact
```

I do not understand the error and the only url I have is in my env file since I'm using mlab mongodb. What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Could you provide a sample of your `.env` file please?

Comment: @JosephReeve added content of .env file in my edit

Comment: I understand that your env var _process.env.DB_CONN_ is not being processed correctly, it's being passed as _undefined_. How are you launching the app?

Comment: how are you running your app ? through some IDE's console ?

Comment: Just wanted to add, this can error can also be caused because of you are writing the wrong variable name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your DB_CONN variable needs some quotes.

`DB_CONN=mongodb://admin:password@ds117931.mlab.com:17931/dem-contact`
should be
`DB_CONN='mongodb://admin:password@ds117931.mlab.com:17931/dem-contact'`

your .env file should be in the root of your project folder ( the same folder as the node_modules folder )

or you can pass the path property in the options to `.config()` like:

`.config({ path: '/somewhere/else/.env' })`

Comment: Still getting the same error after inserting quotes

Comment: after you require the dotenv file, can you console.log the uri?

Comment: is your .env file in the same dir as your node_modules folder? ie, the root of your project?

Comment: Resolved follwoing your answer. I realized that my .env file was not in the root folder. Moved it there and problem was solved

Answer (score 0):

Unrelated to the specific question, but for future readers:

The error `ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE` is thrown in other circumstances too. In my case, I was passing `null` to `path.join()`.